# How to implement strcuture peeling through creating a pass in gcc?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, struct, compiler-optimization

I'm tring to write a pass to implement structure peeling in gcc to make it faster.

Structure peeling is a way to make cache happy through spliting the origin structures into
hot fields and cold fileds. The compiler can run much faster on some specific test cases like 462.libquantum in SPEC-CPU2006.

Demo code1:

```
// origin 
struct node {
  float a;
  long b;
};


// in most functions, 'b' is visited and 'a' is not
void demo_func(struct node* nodes, int size) {
  // 'size' is a huge number here
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    nodes[i]->b += 13; // just for example
  }
}
```

As you can see, the code above is obvious unsufficient, so if we split the structure, it can be much faster.

Demo code2:

```
struct node {
  float* a;
  long* b;
}

void demo_func(struct node* nodes, int size) {
  // 'size' is a huge number here
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    nodes->b[i] += 13;
  }
}
```

icc can do this. So I tried to add a pass in gcc to achieve that. I referred to the implementation of [this article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9874019). But the article didn't mention the specific way to split the structure. So I come here for help.

I put my pass in ipa-late-pass where the article recommended, but I'm not so familiar with gcc, so I'm in a mess now. I don't know where to start.

For one easy problem, how can I get the type of a function parameter in my pass?

```
unsigned int
pass_struct_split::execute (function *)
{
  struct cgraph_node *node;
  FOR_EACH_DEFINED_FUNCTION (node) {
    auto param = DECL_ARGUMENTS (node->decl);
    for (; param; param = DECL_CHAIN (param)) {
      // I want to get the specific type of the param, something like `struct node`
      // Is that possible? Or do I only get the `RECORD_TYPE` instead of the specific `struct node`?
      // I'm confused here.
    }
  }
}
```

And this problem is just a tip of the iceberg, if some of you can offer some comprehensive advice, I'll be so grateful.